# Call to undefined function session_register()

Tags: php, session

```
session_register("username"); // session checker for pages
$_SESSION['username']= $username; // storing username in session
```

I am doing a PHP login system but when I click login system I go this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_register() in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginscript\auth_check.php on line 24

I am using PHP 5.3 how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 27):

This function has been DEPRECATED as of **PHP 5.3.0** and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php

Dont use `session_register()`, `session_is_registered()` and `session_unregister()`

You can use `$_SESSION[]` instead of that

Like as mentioned below:

```
$_SESSION['username']= "Your value";
```

Answer (score 11):

Do not use `session_register("myusername");` instead use

```
$_SESSION['username']= "username"; // storing username in session
```

`session_register` function has been [deprecated](https://www.php.net/session_register) since `PHP5.3`

Answer (score 4):

**Use** `isset($_SESSION['username'])` for check session **Like as:**

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   // go to login page code here.
    // in login page, store data into session, use following:
    $_SESSION['username']="username";
}
else{
   $username=$_SESSION['username'];// get previous session and go your project page
}
```

`session_register()` **function has been deprecated since PHP5.3**